# Problem with subfigure numbering using ContinuedFloat

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I am using the `subfig` package for including subfigures into my thesis. That alone has been going without problem.

However, as soon as I use the `\ContinuedFloat` command in order to split a figure over a single page, the following figure, which also uses the `\ContinuedFloat` command, just carries on with the subfigure numbering (e.g. Figure 2c, 2d instead of 2a, 2b).

If a figure *without* the `\ContinuedFloat` command is inserted it also continues the numbering (e.g. 3f) and only the next figure without this command starts with the normal labelling (e.g. 4a).

This is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[inner=3cm, outer=3cm, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry} %
\geometry{bindingoffset=0.5cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=14cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[]{figure1}\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=12cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[figure1]{figure1}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=14cm]{...figue code...}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{...figue code...}}\\
\caption{[]figure2}\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[figure3]{figure3} \label{figure3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[figure3]{figure3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[figure4]{figure4}\label{figure4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you! I'm obviously new to this, so I had no idea. Every day is a school day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been cross-posted to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/) and there's a possible [solution](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=19752).

The effect is caused by using the `float` package and the `H` option. Removing H and using `!htbp` instead (or less) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to go away if you don't use the `[H]` position specifier (you should also load `caption` before `subfig`). If you really must use `[H]`, you can put this in your preamble and use `\resetsubfigs` after `\begin{figure}` to reset the subfigure labels.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetsubfigs{\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother
```

A fully automated solution may require a lot of hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `\setcounter{subfigure}{number_initial}` or `\setcounter{figure}{number_initial}` and I have solved my problems. The new problem in this case is that you need to know the number or your figure/subfigure, but if you edit the text where your figures are located, this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` in place where you want to reset the counter of subfig.
In your case:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

(...)


\begin{figure}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=12cm]{...figue code...}}
\caption[figure1]{figure1}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=14cm]{...figue code...}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{...figue code...}}\\
\caption{[]figure2}\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

(...)

\end{document}
```