# Not changing subfigure numbering while using command \only<>{ on beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to create slides with sub-figures that will appear and disappear when the next slide will appear. So far everything looks perfect but my main problem is with sub-figure numbering. When the slides are initialized the numbering starts with (a) which is correct. On the second slide I would expect to see the subfigure as (b) but I see (a) again.

While I was looking online for people having the same problem, I found all this possible solutions:

[Beamer + subfigure numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/beamer-subfigure-numbering)

Where I tried all solutions:

```
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}% Reset subfigure counter

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{framenumber}% subfigure counter resets every frame
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{subfigure}{0}}% Resets subfigure counter at start of figure environment
```

Unfortunately this did not work. I searched more and I found also:

[Problem with subfigure numbering using ContinuedFloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51282/problem-with-subfigure-numbering-using-continuedfloat)

Where I tried:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetsubfigs{\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother
```

Which is similar to the previous solution, but unfortunately this did not work either.

Does anyone sees something that I am missing? Where I am going so wrong? Working sample of my code is provided under. In order to test the code just use an blank image.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetsubfigs{\setcounter{sub\@captype}{1}}
\makeatother

%\makeatletter
%\newcommand\hyper@makecurrent[1]{}
%\makeatother

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption} %caption for figures
%\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden} % so so
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %take out the navigation symbols
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriflarge]{structureitalicserif}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}%page numbering

%\makeatletter %reset the numbering on the subfigures (1)
%\@addtoreset{subfigure}{figure} %reset the numbering on the subfigures (2)
%\makeatother %reset the numbering on the subfigures (3)

\title[Title Description] % (optional, only for long titles)
{Main Title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\vspace*{-2.2em}
\author[Author 1, Author 2]% (optional, for multiple authors)
{Number 1 \and Number 2}
\institute[Institution Here] % (optional)
{
\\
\medskip
{
\emph{author1@email.com}
\emph{author1@email.com}
}
}
\date[2014]{Presentation: 1, 2014}
\subject{Department \LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
 \begin{center}
 % Upper part of the page
 \vspace*{1.0em}
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{image}\\ [0.3cm]    

 \emph{Supervisor:} \\  
  Dr.~First name \\
  \textsc{Last name} 
 \end{center}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1} \label{sec:one}

 \subsection{Subsection 1}
 \begin{frame}{Frame Text 1}
  \setbeamercovered{dynamic}%Makes the text appear before it presents nice!!!! 
  \begin{columns}[t] % contents are top vertically aligned
  \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % each column can also be its own environment
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text column subfigure 1:~\autoref{fig:colsub1}.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text column subfigure 2:~Figure:~1b.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text column subfigure 3:~Figure:~1c.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text column subfigure 4:~Figure:~1d.
      \end{itemize}  
  \end{column}
 \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % alternative top-align that's better for graphics
  \begin{figure}
  \resetsubfigs
    \only<1>{%
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \caption{Column subcation 1} \label{fig:colsub1}
        \hspace*{-1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=7.0cm,height=5cm]{image}
        %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./pdf/core}
        %\includegraphics[height=9.5cm]{./pdf/core}
        \vspace*{-0.6cm}
      \end{subfigure}\hfill
    }
    \only<2>{%
      \vspace*{-1.5cm}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \caption{Column subcation 2} \label{fig:receiver}
        \hspace*{-0.5cm}
        \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{image}
      \end{subfigure}
    }
    \only<3>{%
      \vspace*{-1.5cm}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \caption{Column subcation 3} \protect\label{fig:worst}
        %\hspace*{1cm}
        \vspace*{0.1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{image}
      \end{subfigure}
    }
    \only<4>{%
      \vspace*{-1.5cm}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \caption{Column subcation 4} \protect\label{fig:best}
        %\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \vspace*{0.1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{image}
      \end{subfigure}
    }
  \captionsetup{justification=centering} %Center a two line caption
  \caption{Main Caption for Column subfigures} \protect\label{fig:5}%~\cite{wsn}
   \end{figure}
  \end{column}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related but please don't use captions in presentations. They serve no purpose. If you really really have to use the slide number.

Comment: Hello and @percusse and thank you for your time and effort reading my question. I am a bit confused if you mean the captions on the figures or the slide/page number?

Comment: @Thanos: References to objects (like citations, sections, figures/tables and even frames) only make sense when the audience can flip back to what you're referring to. So if you call something `Figure 1` and `Figure 2`, but 10 slides later refer back to `Figure 1`, the audience may very well have no clue what `Figure 1` looks like. In those instances it's a good idea to repeat/duplicate the image. As such, there's typically no need to number and reference things explicitly.

Comment: @Werner: Hello again thank you for your time and effort reading and replying to my question. You are absolutely right about that. The reason that I am enumerating the figures/sub-figures is that I am using references on my bibliography file. Plus I amazed with the ability that I can click on a reference point while I am presenting so I can link the images later on my presentation. Apart from these reasons, I totally agree with you and percusse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after all of experimentation I found the solution to my problem. I noticed that things get complicated when I use the final `\only<4>{}`. If I do not use the final `\only<4>{}` the enumeration continues normally but not the expected output.

So I searched for alternative solutions and I found the `\visible{}`, with reference to this question:

[Beamer: How to show images as step-by-step images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683093/beamer-how-to-show-images-as-step-by-step-images)

So my final solution is provided in case that someone else might have the same problem. For each picture you might need to play with `\vspace*{-1.0}` etc. in order to get the desired output.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref} % autoref

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden} % so so
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %take out the navigation symbols
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriflarge]{structureitalicserif}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber} %page numbering

\title[Title Description] % (optional, only for long titles){Main Title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\vspace*{-2.2em}
\author[Author 1, Author 2]% (optional, for multiple authors){Number 1 \and Number 2}
\institute[Institution Here] % (optional)
{
\\
\medskip
{
\emph{author1@email.com}
\emph{author1@email.com}
}
}
\date[2014]{Presentation: 1, 2014}
\subject{Department \LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
  \begin{center}
    % Upper part of the page
    \vspace*{1.0em}
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{image}\\ [0.3cm]    
    \emph{Supervisor:} \\  
      Dr.~First name \\
      \textsc{Last name} 
  \end{center}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1} \label{sec:one}
  \subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame Text 1}
 \setbeamercovered{dynamic}%Makes the text appear before it presents nice!!!!
  \begin{columns}[t] % contents are top vertically aligned
   \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % each column can also be its own environment
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text subfigure:~\autoref{fig:a}.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text subfigure:~\autoref{fig:b}.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text subfigure:~\autoref{fig:c}.
        \item<+-| alert@+> Text subfigure:~\autoref{fig:d}.
    \end{itemize}  
   \end{column}
  \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % alternative top-align that's better for graphics
   \begin{figure}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
     \visible<1-1>{%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
       \caption{First subfigure}
       \label{fig:a}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
      \end{subfigure}\\
     } % Closing visible<1>
    \vspace*{-4.7cm}
     \visible<2-2>{%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
       \caption{Second subfigure}
       \label{fig:b}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
      \end{subfigure}\\
     } % Closing visible<2>
    \vspace*{-4.7cm}
     \visible<3-3>{%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
       \caption{Third subfigure}
       \label{fig:c}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
      \end{subfigure}\\
     } % Closing visible<3>
    \vspace*{-4.7cm}
     \visible<4-4>{
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
       \caption{Fourth subfigure}
       \label{fig:d}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
      \end{subfigure}%
     } % Closing visible<4>
    \captionsetup{justification=centering} %Center a two line caption
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
   \end{figure}
  \end{column}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample of output]